# Running a single test class from sbt , in a multi module project

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I would like to run a single test class in a non interactive mode, in a multi module project.
I know how to do it when interactively first launching sbt, then selecting the project, and then using the "testOnly".
How to do it all via one command (or a script)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that with the following syntax

```
sbt "project-name/testOnly classpath.of.Test"
```

So for example

running the Test `biz.neumann.MySpec` in the submodule `logic` you can use this command on the shell:

```
sbt "logic/testOnly biz.neumann.MySpec"
```

The `"` are important otherwise each withespace is interpreted as as an separator for additional arguments.

Comment: Thanks Andreas.
I was wondering why it didn't work for me, the quotes made all the difference.

Comment: You may use asterix if you don't wont to type the package and class name like
`sbt "logic/testOnly *.MySpec"`

Comment: Answer exemplifies this just fine, but to be explicit DO NOT include the ".java" on the test file path. Had me going for a bit...